# How to initialize large array parallel with PLINQ?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, plinq

I am trying to initialize a simple (but large) array, using PLINQ:

```
void Test(int width, int height)
{
    var foo = new Foo[width * height];
    foo.AsParallel().ForAll(c => new Foo());
}
```

But this will leave me with an array of width x height null (uninitialized) elements.

Surely this must be possible since this operation can simply be paralyzed(?).

What is the correct syntax to perform the initialization with PLINQ?

Comment: ForAll takes an `Action` delegate, not a `Func`,  The newly created `Foo` does not get assigned back to the related array element.

Comment: @NathanA: Thanks for pointing that out. Somehow I'll often seem to miss this small syntactical but crucial detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't doubt that there is a way to initialize an array with LINQ in parallel, but, I'd suggest simply using Parallel.For instead:

```
var foo = new Foo[width * height];
Parallel.For(0, foo.Length, i => foo[i] = new Foo());
```

Edit: Since you want a proper PLINQ solution (also, fixed typo as you pointed out):

```
var foo = Enumerable.Range(0, width * height)
                    .AsParallel()
                    .Select(x => new Foo())
                    .ToArray();
```

Comment: its true but its not plinq, its tpl

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Sometimes what the OP asks for is not what the OP needs :)

Comment: Okay, although this solves my actual problem, I'll leave the bonus points for the solution with PLINQ :)

Comment: @Stefan: Updated with a PLINQ answer as well.

Comment: yes . `foo.Count` or `width * height`. nice @willaien